# Fourier Series through set of nD points

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

I know it is possible to find a Fourier Series that defines a function though a set of 2D points (as shown [here](https://gofigure.impara.ai/)), but I want to know how to do this for a set of $n$ dimensional points.

I am assuming I would have to apply a Fourier transform on the data, but how is that information used to construct the function? In 2D space, the function is created by summing complex numbers that are computed using the coefficients.

$$f(x)\sim\frac{a_{0}}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(a_{k}\cos\left(kx\right)+b_{k}\sin\left(kx\right)\right)$$

What I need help with is generalizing that equation. I do not know how the nth dimension contributes to this function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't my field, but because of my job, I read once a paper about signal processing mentioning multidimensional Fourier Series. I had a hard time finding it again: it's [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00034-019-01133-x) behind a paywall, but luckily available for free [on the arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.08117). The equation 1 is for 1D, equation 10 for 2D, and 19 for nD. Quite frankly, I do not understand the peculiarities of the form, specially why the summation ranges differ in that way.

Comment: Hopefully, someone competent will soon join the conversation and provide better sources, but in the meantime, I hope this helps a little.

Comment: Thank you! I took a look at the paper and unfortunately I am ill equipped to decipher it, the summations are throwing me off. Definitely the right thing; hopefully someone can explain it well.